# get user token of user running explorer.exe

Tags: powershell, impersonation

I am getting an error when trying to get the user's token that is running explorer.exe.  I am not sure what my is causing the error.

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid
> token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated." At line:13 char:26
>
> - ... essToken = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity -Arg ...
> - ```
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

```
# Specify the username of the target user
$targetUsername = "$env:username"

# Get the processes running under the target user
$processes = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'" | Where-Object { $_.GetOwner().User -eq $targetUsername }

if ($processes.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No processes found for the user: $targetUsername"
} else {
    foreach ($process in $processes) {
        # Get the security token of the process
        $processHandle = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessById($process.ProcessId).Handle
        $processToken = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity -ArgumentList $processHandle).Token

        Write-Host "Token for $targetUsername : $processToken"
    }
}
```

Comment: For command to work, you have to be an Admin on both local and remote machines.  Can you open a File Explorer as an admin and access the file by using \\server name\c$\file name ?  Notice I used a dollar sign instead of a colon which is required when accessing a file as an Admin.

Comment: It does not use a remote machine.  All of the code is local.  The code is ran as admin.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-duplicatetokenex?redirectedfrom=MSDN

And: [How to get Windows SYSTEM user token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553615/how-to-get-windows-system-user-token)

You are trying to use a handle that can not be used as a token for impersonation. The handle must have the `TOKEN_DUPLICATE` access right which `explorer.exe` does not. Try using `DuplicateTokenEx` which will allow you to  specify the access rights you want for the new token. See the links above for further guidance.

Please try and let me know if this helps.